# Can't seem to run Anaconda on Heroku

Tags: heroku, anaconda, buildpack

I've followed the official guidelines from Heroku on how to set up an Anaconda buildpack from

> https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/conda/conda-buildpack

Including copying the

> environment.yml

file as is from the page, but when I test which Python am I running on, I see that I am not running on Anaconda as the tutorial suggests:

> Running python on guarded-cove-86401... up, run.5833 (Free)
>   Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19)
>   [GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Please advise